# scrapy email Stats or Error

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

i have multiple spiders in my project i run them at the same time. i want when each crawler finish either on **ERROR** or **COMPLETION** i receive an Email with **STATS** or **ERROR**

i go though Doc

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html

i added these  settings in project settings.py

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy.contrib.statsmailer.StatsMailer': 500,
}

STATSMAILER_RCPTS=['abc@gmail.com']
```

but i am not able to receive any email , i am sure i am missing something any help will be appriciated , i think i need to setup SMTP server then it will work but i don't know how to configure that or anything else what i required to do for sending stats email

Comment: You always can just write logs to a file and then `mail` it

Comment: @Leo it doesn't make sense when scrapy allow automatic emailing why we genrate log file and then email ?

Comment: Just saying there's a way and it works.

Comment: For sure you need to setup a mail transfer agent like sendmail etc.  You are probably going to get more help asking another mail-specific question on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/statsmailer.py). Note the line

```
 crawler.connect(o.stats_spider_closed, signal=signals.stats_spider_closed)
```

The source doc cleary stats

> StatsMailer extension sends an email when a spider finishes scraping

The SatsMailer is only connected to a single signal. Why not create your own extension (you could copy-paste the existing code) and also connect it to one of [Scarpy's signals](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html?highlight=signals#module-scrapy.signals)

Comment: thanks for your reply i saw these classes early , as i am nob in python i m not understanding how to use them , if you can paste some example or link where it is used properly i ll be very thankful to you

Comment: if you see this extension is already enabled by me 


EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy.contrib.statsmailer.StatsMailer': 500,
}

Comment: You can simply copy the existing code and add connect more signals to the event. Since you will be using your own extension, you can remove the scrapy extension from `EXTENSIONS` and add your own to it.